# Django url patterns, redirect from root to other url

Tags: python, django

This should be an easy enough problem to solve for you guys:
I just started working with Django, and I'm doing some routing. This is my `urls.py` in the root of the project:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('', include('dashboard.urls')),
]
```

This is the routing in my `dashboard app`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Now let's say I want my users to be redirected to `/dashboard` if they go to the root of the website. So I would use `''` as a route in the `urls.py` in the root, and then have everyone sent to `/dashboard` from the `urls.py` in the `dashboard app`. But when I do this I get the following warning:

```
?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '/dashboard' [name='index'] has a route beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'.
```

So I tried to use `'/'` instead of `''`, but since a trailing `/` is automatically removed from an url, the url wouldn't match the pattern. Should I ignore/mute this warning or is there another way to go about it?

This is the code that worked perfectly but gave me a warning earlier:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/dashboard', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('dashboard.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Please show the code that gave the warning `urls.W002`.

Comment: @Alasdair updated

Comment: You say that `path('/dashboard', views.index, name='index'),` 'worked perfectly' - what doesn't work when you change it to `path('dashboard', views.index, name='index'),`? Note that 'redirect' has a very specific meaning - it will change the URL in the browser e.g. from `http://localhost:8000/` to `http://localhost:8000/dashboard`. Do you want to do that? Or just display the same page for `http://localhost:8000/` and `http://localhost:8000/dashboard` but leave the URL unchanged?

Comment: @Alasdair It would see the route as `localhost:8000dashboard` instead of `localhost:8000/dashboard`.
I would want it to change the url and not just display the same view

Comment: *What* sees the route as `localhost:8000dashboard`? I think you're mistaken. You don't need the leading slash before `'dashboard'`, just as you don't need it before `'admin/'`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `RedirectView` to redirect from `/` to `/dashboard/`. Then use `'dashboard'` when including the dashboard urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='dashboard:index')
  path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
]
```

You can then remove `'dashboard'` from the path in `dashboard/urls.py`, as it is already in the `include()`.

```
app_name = 'dashboard'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

I've added `app_name='dashboard'` to match the namespace used above in `pattern_name='dashboard:index'`.

Note that Django projects usually use URLs with a trailing slash, e.g. `/dashboard/` instead of `dashboard`.

If you really want to use URLs like `/dashboard` without a trailing slash, then the include should be

```
path('dashboard', include('dashboard.urls')),
```

If you do this, I suggest you set [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#append-slash) to `False` in your settings.

Comment: I'm new to Python/Django as well.  In my app, using ```path('', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='pollapp:index'))``` threw a 'NoReverseMatch at /' exception.  I resolved the exception by changing to ```path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='pollapp/'))```.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^contacts/', include('appname.contacts.urls')),
    url(r'^comments/', include('appname.urls')),
    url(r'^subscriptions/', include('appname.partner.urls')),
    url(r'^', RedirectView.as_view(url="/admin/"))
]
```

This is what I've done in my project so whenever the user go to `127.0.0.1:8000` it redirects to `/admin`

Comment: You need `r'^$'`, otherwise this will match all URLs not just the root. It would be better to include a leading slash `/dashboard/` (or use `pattern_name` and reverse the URL instead of hardcoding it).

Comment: Or you can add that url as the last one! obviously you need to remove this line: path('', views.index, name='index'),

Comment: It still sees the first url pattern as `^`, and it sees the second one as `$^`. I do not know why it does not recognize them as an empty route. I get this error back `The empty path didn't match any of these.`, which makes sense.

Comment: @Snackoverflow I've edited my answer providing everything there is in my urls.py, this is what I've done in my project and it works redirecting '^' to 'admin/'